# IE 9 stops working when using getIntersectionList function

Tags: javascript, svg

I have this SVG code:

```
<svg id="svgSurface" width="500" height="500">
    <defs>
        <marker id="Triangle" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="0" refY="0" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
            <path d="M 0 0 L 20 10 L 0 20 z" fill="red" fill-opacity="1">
            </path>
        </marker>
    </defs>
    <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="100" y2="100" class="Line" marker-end="url(#Triangle)"></line>
</svg>
```

and some javascript code:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("svgSurface");

var svgRect = svg.createSVGRect();
svgRect.x = 0;
svgRect.y = 0;
svgRect.width = 50;
svgRect.height = 50;

var nodes = svg.getIntersectionList(svgRect, null);

alert(nodes.length);
```

Here is a working example in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gYaEX/1/

As you can see I try to get all nodes whose rendered content intersects the specified rectangle svgRect. In Chrome it works properly but in IE it always crashes and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it crashes that's a bug in IE which you should report to Microsoft, having said that you are using it incorrectly as you should be passing in an element and not null as the last argument. In your case you probably want this:

```
var nodes = svg.getIntersectionList(svgRect, svg);
```